# See if folder x has all the files in folder z

Tags: macos, terminal, comparison

I have 2 folders, and I want to know if `folder#1` has all the files in `folder#2`

How can I check this?

Comment: A little more information please. What OS? Do you want scripting based solutions, or purely third party programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Giving that `folder2` for example has an extra file named `test4`, but they share all other files in common, you can always use `diff`.

```
diff folder1 folder2
```

In our case that would return:

```
Only in folder2: test4
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to find missing files/directories on folder2 from folder1, you do:

```
ls folder2 > /tmp/f2.txt
ls folder1 | grep -v -f /tmp/f2.txt
```

That will list all items present in folder1 but not in folder2, you can do the opposite to find both differences.